# Using OnPropertyChanged with entity framework code first

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am Using C# 2010 Entity framework code first
If I have A class like this

```
partial class test    
{
        public double value1;
        public double value2;
        public double value3;
        public double totals;
}
```

That generated by code

how could I create partial class to calc totals

```
partial class test    
{
        public double totals { get  { return value1 + value2 + value3; }    }
```

1 - you know it is not practical to change the generated class.
2 - there is no way to partially define the property totals.
3 - And using metadata class does not update totals till savechanges.

I'll appreciate If anyone could define how can I implement OnpropertyChanged and used to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property in the second class is missing the "get" keyword:

```
partial class test    
{
        public double totals {  
            get { return value1 + value2 + value3; }
        }
}
```

Alternatively you could define a Total() method.

As far as I can tell from your question ("how could I create partial class to calc totals"), you don't need to use OnPropertyChanged because the totals property/method will run the calculation each time with the new values in totals. You can remove that field from the original class as it's a calculation and really shouldn't be stored.

If you must actually update a total value in the database you can use the OnPropertyChanged partial methods as you suggested. You'll need to use properties to call the new method:

```
partial class test
{
    public double Value1
    {
        get { return value1; }
        set
        {
            value1 = value;
            Onvalue1Changed(value);
        }
    }

    partial void Onvalue1Changed(double value)
    {
        UpdateTotals();
    }

    private void UpdateTotals()
    {
        totals = value1 + value2 + value3;
    }
}
```

You should make the original fields private and only provide public access through the property. This is not only better code design but also allows you to implement the kind of functionality you desire.

There are, of course, other patterns that you can follow, but this should get you started.

Comment: I need Totals to be update if value1 or value2 or value3 changed. also I can't remove totals from original class while it is auto generated by ef and it is exist in database

Comment: Dirty database design... okay well in that case you can just define partial OnPropertyChanged methods in your partial class (e.g. Onvalue1Changed(double value)). It's explained well here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716747.aspx

Comment: I am using code first. could you give me example how could I add Onpropertychanged to my partial class. the example you attach is for EntityObject

Comment: You must use properties to set the values that trigger the update to totals. You can't include any extra logic when setting a field directly. This is the pattern provided for us in .NET languages. It is by design. You have some options when it comes to how you execute that logic, but it needs to happen either in a property or method. It might seem like magic when using EntityObject, but if you look under the hood this is the same behaviour (more or less).

Comment: Thanks Kad81 but your sample won't work on partial class. I can't define the same property twice. If I follow your way value1 would be defined twice . first in the automaticlly generated class and in my partial class to include OnValue1Change.

Comment: You're right. That's why you need to name them differently (Value1 vs. value1). You make the fields private, and then the only thing that client code will see is test.Value1 (not test.value1). For more info on naming conventions in C#, please have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As far as I can see both have only been defined once: value1 in the first file and Value1 in the second. And the Value1 property reads and writes to the value1 field.

Comment: You'll need to add a property for each field that you want to have this functionality (Value1, Value2 and Value3). I have only put the first in the example to get you going. Then client code will need to set the values only using these properties (not the fields directly). If you're saying that the value of totals is not updated in the database, be sure to call SaveChanges() on your context. Sorry to the mods for all the comments--the OP isn't able to chat.

Comment: Thanks My mistake I still binding value1. now it works thank you very much. I'll accept your answer. but could you help me to implement onpropertychanged and OnpropertyChanging inside my code because I need it a lot